# Determining the differences between two MySQL database schemas

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to get any missing tables or fields in database BB that are in database AA. I was using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns to get the info. So, I wrote a 'missing record' query to find them.  In testing, I used 2 databases where I knew that BB had 1 missing table and 1 missing field in another table.
Here's my 1st try:

```
SELECT AA.table_name,
       AA.column_name,
       BB.table_name,
       BB.column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns AS AA
       LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns AS BB
              ON ( AA.table_name = bb.table_name )
                 AND ( AA.column_name = BB.column_name )
WHERE  AA.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
   AND BB.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
   AND BB.column_name IS NULL
```

This returned 0 records. So, then I tried:

```
SELECT AA.table_name,
       AA.column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns AS AA
WHERE  AA.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT BB.table_name,
                         BB.column_name
                  FROM   information_schema.columns AS BB
                  WHERE  BB.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05')
```

I again got 0 records. Lastly I tried this:

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_name
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                        column_name
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                        column_name
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05') AS tbl
GROUP  BY table_name,
          column_name
HAVING Count(*) = 1
```

This produced the desired results.

While I don't mind using the 3rd query, I can't figure out why the first two didn't work. I'd like to know for future reference. Can anyone spot the problem?

---

Update:
For those interested, here's 4 queries that work, and the times it took to run each one. Listed in order of fastest first, with times listed below the query.

```
SELECT AA.table_name,
       AA.column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns AS AA
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT table_name,
                         column_name
                  FROM   information_schema.columns
                  WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04') BB
              ON AA.table_name = BB.table_name
                 AND AA.column_name = BB.column_name
WHERE  AA.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
       AND BB.table_name IS NULL;
```

.047 seconds

```
SELECT table_name,
       column_name
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                        column_name
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                        column_name
        FROM   information_schema.columns
        WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05') AS tbl
GROUP  BY table_name,
          column_name
HAVING Count(*) = 1;
```

.078 seconds

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                column_name,
                Concat(table_name, '--', column_name) AS tc
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
HAVING tc NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT Concat(table_name, '--', column_name)
                 FROM   information_schema.columns
                 WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04');
```

.125 seconds (a new solution I thought of this morning)

```
SELECT aa.table_name,
       aa.column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns aa
WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM   information_schema.columns
                       WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
                              AND table_name = aa.table_name
                              AND column_name = aa.column_name);
```

44.382 seconds. Obviously not a good real world solution.

Comment: information_schema is relatively expensive to query, because the tables there aren't real and queries often examine more internal structures than the query actually requires.  This helps explain why the first query is so much faster -- `LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) BB` actually creates an ephemeral temporary table `BB` *first*, so what appears to be the second table in the query is actually fully populated before the outer query is run,  in contrast to the very slow variant shown last, which is likely making a request from i_s for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the records looked like so:

```
   schema              table    column
   ----------------    -----    ------
1. wireless-2015-05    T1       F1
2. wireless-2015-05    T1       F2
3. wireless-2015-05    T2       F1
4. wireless-2015-04    T1       F1
```

Notice that wireless-2015-04 is missing table T2 and column T1.F2. We'll take this example in the description and in SQL Fiddle examples. You were pretty close in your first two attempts. Just a little modification (included below) could have nailed it.

**Query 1**

Let's break down the first query. We will leave the `where` clause out since the above example has only those 2 schema that were mentioned in the `where` clause.

```
SELECT ...
FROM information_schema.columns AS AA
LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns AS BB 
    on aa.table_name = bb.table_name
    and aa.column_name = bb.column_name
```

The first record of `wireless-2015-05 + T1 + F1` is matched (based on table and column name) with all records in the same table. So,

- AA's record #1 will match BB's record #1 and #4
- AA's record #2 will match BB's record #2
- AA's record #3 will match BB's record #3
- AA's record #4 will match BB's record #1 and #4

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b704/4

There will be no record with `NULL` BB.column_name. So no records are fetched. However, that's not what you are looking for.

**Query 1 improvement**

You could re-write Query 1 to give you the right results using something like this:

```
SELECT AA.table_name,
       AA.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns AS AA
LEFT JOIN 
( 
  select table_name, column_name from
  information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
) BB
  on AA.table_name = BB.table_name
  and AA.column_name = BB.column_name
WHERE 
  AA.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
  and BB.table_name is null
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b704/10

**Query 2**

Basically, Query 2's `NOT EXISTS` sub-query is missing a clause that matches AA's columns. So that won't yield you results

**Query 2 improvement**

That query can be correctly improved by doing something like this:

```
select aa.table_name, aa.column_name
from information_schema.columns aa
where table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
and not exists (
  select 1
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
  and table_name = aa.table_name
  and column_name = aa.column_name
);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b704/9

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. If you look at my edits, you'll see benchmarking results. Your re-write of query 1 gave the best time.

Comment: Very nice work, @TomCollins. Thank you for sharing the benchmarking results.

Answer (score 0):

Your first query should be like,

```
Select AA.*
(
    SELECT table_name,
           column_name
    From information_schema.columns
    Where table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
) AA
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT table_name,
           column_name
    From information_schema.columns
    Where table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
)BB
on AA.table_name = BB.table_name
AND AA.column_name = BB.column_name

WHERE BB.table_name is null or BB.column_name is null
```

**YOUR QUERY ISSUE:**

you have placed where query with wrong conditions

```
WHERE  AA.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'
   AND BB.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
   AND BB.column_name IS NULL
```

When the records are not present in BB then `BB.table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'` this condition became false so the entire result will be false, so you are not getting result.

And for the second query I think **@zedfoxus** is right.

You might also using the concept of EXCEPT which gives you the desire result.

The following query returns any distinct values from the query to the left of the [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator that are not also found on the right query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-05'

EXCEPT

SELECT DISTINCT table_name,
                column_name
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_schema = 'wireless-2015-04'
```

Comment: The EXCEPT clause didn't work. Googling it shows that clause doesn't work in MySQL.